# Weak Global Dimension and Global Dimension

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, global-dimension

Let $R$ be a commutative unit ring (not necessarily Noetherian). Is there an example such that weak global dimension of $R$ is finite but the global dimension of $R$ is infinite? Can we find such an example if $R$ is a local ring?

Answer (score 2):

There exists a von Neumann regular ring ("absolutely flat ring", and so it has weak dimension $0$) which has infinite global dimension, so the answer to the first question is "yes."  See [this mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/299700/19965) which refers to an interesting article by Osofsky about $\prod_\kappa F$.

The ring is nowhere near local, of course.  I do not have an example or proof handy for that case.  A local ring with weak dimension $0$ is already a division ring, so it'll have to be something with positive weak dimension.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of rschweib refers to a result of Osofsky that gives a ring with infinite global dimension but finite weak global dimension.

Another result of Osofsky gives a local example.

In Corollary 2 of

*Osofsky, B. L.*, [**Global dimension of valuation rings**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1994637), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 127, 136-149 (1967). [ZBL0145.27602](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0145.27602)

she shows that there is a valuation domain $R$ with infinite global dimension.

But valuation domains are precisely the commutative local rings of weak global dimension at most one. See, for example, Corollary 4.2.6 of

*Glaz, Sarah*, [**Commutative coherent rings**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0084570), Lecture Notes in Mathematics. 1371. Berlin etc.: Springer-Verlag. xi, 347 p. (1989). [ZBL0745.13004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0745.13004).

Comment: *valuation domains are precisely the commutative local rings of weak global dimension at most one* really? Wow! That’s neat!

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, it is. It's not that hard to prove, but I struggled to find a source that gave a statement and proof without proving more. Maybe an easier sourse from which to distill a proof is https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/092S.